# jQuery click event handle both class element and element inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="eventContainer" id="dennaVecka" style="background-color: #2B4699;">
    <p>Denna vecka</p>
</div><!--eventContainer ends--> 
<div class="eventList" id="dennaVecka_table">
...
</div>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
eventID = null;
$('.eventContainer p, .eventContainer').click(function (e) {
//eventID = $(this).attr('id');
eventID = e.target.id;
$('.eventList#' + eventID + '_table').fadeIn(300);
//alert(e.target.id);
});
```

I want: When div class eventContainer *or* the paragraph inside it is clicked, I want to use the ID of eventContainer (id="dennaVecka") to display the div class eventList beneath it. My problem with the current setup is that I don't know how to get the ID of eventContainer if the paragraph is clicked. If I click the paragraph I will get the ID of the paragraph ("undefined").

**Is there a way to get the ID of eventContainer in jQuery no matter if I click the div or the paragraph?**

Maybe I should setup the HTML in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that click event bubbles up to the parent container. In this case you can bind only one event handler to `.eventContainer` and read `this.id` to get container id:

```
$('.eventContainer').click(function (e) {
    eventID = this.id;
    $('.eventList#' + eventID + '_table').fadeIn(300);
});
```

So if you click `p` element inside `.eventContainer` event will still be handled by above listener on `.eventContainer`, with `this` pointing to it.

Comment: Works! Thank you! Is it calling the .eventContainer-selector which makes the bubbling stop here and show that ID and for example not the ID of the parent of .eventContainer?

Comment: When you click `p` element inside `.eventContainer` this event is not handled by anything (you don't bind events to `p`). However click event bubble up to the parent, then to the next parent untill it reaches `html` element. You bind click event to `.eventContainer` so it will detect events on child `p` element also, because this event eventually bubbles up to it. From there you can get `id` reliably.